# The 1st parameter must be String

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

What is wrong in the following piece of code-:

```
            <?php

            if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
            {
                require 'connection.php';
                create_user();
            }

            function create_user(){
                global $connect;

                $name = $_POST["name"];
                $username = $_POST["username"];
                $password = $_POST["password"];
                $age = $_POST["age"];

                $query = "Insert into usertable(name, username, password, age) values ('$name','$username','$password','$age');";

                mysqli_connect($connect, $query) or die (mysqli_error($connect));
                mysqli_close($connect);
            }

            ?>
```

It is giving the following error , the first parameter I am giving is String only-:

```
        <br />
            <b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_connect() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in 
            <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\insertuser.php</b> on line 
            <b>19</b>
            <br />
            can't connect
```

the line 19 is                  mysqli_connect($connect, $query) or die (mysqli_error($connect));

Comment: when you do get it to work, what is wrong is 2nd level sql injection

Comment: According to [mysqli_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php), you are not calling with the appropriate parameters. What is the output from `print_r($connect)`?

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS.. this is an SQL injection attack waiting to happen.  Read about prepared statements.  Seriously.

Comment: Hi JRD , nothing extra is coming. the same error is repeating

Answer (score 1):

Use `prepared statements` with binding. No sql injection. Turn on **error reporting.**

Here it is end-to-end.

Change the connection parameters.

Your variables would naturally come from `$_POST[]` whereas I hard-coded them. You get the idea. I hope.

Never use user-supplied data without binding the way you did. Even in insert statements. Unless you want 2nd level sql injection attacks.

### Schema

```
create table data
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    `name` varchar(100) not null, 
    email varchar(100) not null, 
    phone varchar(100) not null, 
    facebook varchar(100) not null, 
    linkedin varchar(100) not null, 
    twitter varchar(100) not null, 
    yourstory varchar(100) not null
);
```

### PHP

```
<?php
    //mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);
    error_reporting(E_ALL); // report all PHP errors
    ini_set("display_errors", 1); 
    echo "start<br/>";
    $name='a';
    $email='b';
    $phone='c';
    $facebook='d';
    $linkedin='e';
    $twitter='f';
    $yourstory='g';

    try {
        $mysqli= new mysqli('host', 'dbuser', 'password', 'databaseName');
        if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
            die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
                . $mysqli->connect_error);
        }
        echo "I am connected and feel happy.<br/>";
        $query = "INSERT INTO `data`(`name`, email, phone, facebook, linkedin, twitter, yourstory)";
        $query .= " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        echo "1<br/>";
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
        echo "2<br/>";
        // note the 7 s's below, s is for string
        $stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $name, $email, $phone,$facebook,$linkedin,$twitter,$yourstory);
        echo "3<br/>";
        $stmt->execute();
        echo "4<br/>";
        $stmt->close(); 
        $mysqli->close();
    } catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) { 
        throw $e; 
    } 
?>
```

### Results

```
select * from data;
+----+------+-------+-------+----------+----------+---------+-----------+
| id | name | email | phone | facebook | linkedin | twitter | yourstory |
+----+------+-------+-------+----------+----------+---------+-----------+
|  1 | a    | b     | c     | d        | e        | f       | g         |
+----+------+-------+-------+----------+----------+---------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are wanting to pass your connection object into mysqli_query, rather than mysqli_connect.

I am assuming connect.php has a mysqli_connect statement in it.

Update your code to read,

```
            mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die (mysqli_error($connect));
```

And see if it works.

Comment: <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in 
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\insertuser.php</b> on line 
<b>19</b>
<br />

Comment: Please try the updated snippet I have edited. You need to pass two params, $connection and $query. I was following PHP documentation for OOP not procedural, but this code is procedural.

Comment: <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in 
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\insertuser.php</b> on line 
<b>27</b>
<br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in 
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\insertuser.php</b> on line 
<b>27</b>
<br />

Comment: Can you please include source of connection.php? That will help, as that file likely creates global variables needed at query time.